# Авторизация Вконтакте на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте есть проблема нужно [авторизироваться вконтакте](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) только средствами JavaScript и HTML, мне в итоге нужна переменная JavaScript с access_token, сам уже перепробовал кучу способов ничего не работало от отчаяния решил обратиться за помощью. Зарание спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В качестве клиента может выступать
> любое Desktop/мобильное приложение,
> имеющее доступ к управлению
> Web-браузером

Т.е. ваш код должен выполняться «над» браузером, чтобы иметь возможность получить из того access_token после редиректа на oauth.vk.com/blank.html

Под iOS, в десктоп приложении с браузерным компонентом — легко. Просто из браузера — облом по причине политики [Same Origin Policy](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%E0%E2%E8%EB%EE_%EE%E3%F0%E0%ED%E8%F7%E5%ED%E8%FF_%E4%EE%EC%E5%ED%E0) - скриптом с вашего домена, вы не получите/не измените данные, полученные с другого домена, oauth.vk.com в данном случае. (Если только vk.com не пойдёт лично вам навстречу и не допишет в заголовки ответов своих серверов разрешение кросс-доменности именно с вами. Или со всеми, что такую дырищу откроет!)

Из топорных решений видел:

1. Инструкции типа "сейчас у вас в новом окне попросят разрешения и потом вы просто скопируйте к нам сюда адресную строку из того окна, пожалуйста";
2. Под Chrome кто-то ваял типа плагин, который по сути кусок JS, выполняющийся-таки на той пустой странице oauth.vk.com/blank.html и сливающий полученный код на нужный сервер.

Из собственного опыта: на сервере имитировать браузер с помощью curl — плохой вариант, т.к. VK проверяет ip с которого поступает запрос. Как правило клиент сидит напримет в Питере, а сервер вашего приложения в Германии, и при таком космически быстром "перемещении" клиента VK включает паранойю и просит обычно ввести цифры телефона. Что пока не реализовано для OAuth протокола, и тот просто возвращает сообщение о дыре в безопасности: "Security Breach". И никакого жетона не выдаёт.

По-«правильному» видимо, только писать именно отдельное приложение, имеющее в обёртке свой браузер.